# Images not exported to executable jar file

Tags: java, image, maven, jar, weka

I'm modifying Weka, an open-source Maven project, and my modifications are running perfectly on eclipse. However, when I export to an executable jar file, I get a null pointer exception, because it's not able to find the images I created and added to the project upon `getImage()` calls.

It seems that this is a rather common problem with jar files, so I tried using the URL method to load, but upon further investigation, when I look into the jar file with SecureZIP, the images(.png) that I added to the project are not even in the jar (however, the images (.png) that were in the original open source distribution were, despite the fact that all the images were in the same folder and of the same type (.png) designated by the build path in the source).  Is there something I'm forgetting to do? Why are my images not exporting to the jar, but the other images in the folder are?

Library Handling is: "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". 
Images are in src/main/java/weka/gui.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
  <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <!-- weka-version -->
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>weka-stable</name>
  <description>The Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis (WEKA), a machine learning workbench. This is the stable version. Apart from bugfixes, this version does not receive any other updates.
  </description>
  <url>http://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/</url>
  <organization>
    <name>University of Waikato, Hamilton, NZ</name>
    <url>http://www.waikato.ac.nz/</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License 3</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>wekateam</id>
      <name>The WEKA Team</name>
      <email>wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
      <name>wekalist</name>
      <subscribe>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist</subscribe>
      <unsubscribe>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist</unsubscribe>
      <archive>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/htdig/wekalist/</archive>
    </mailingList>
  </mailingLists>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
  </parent>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/branches/stable-3-8/weka</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/branches/stable-3-8/weka</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/branches/stable-3-8/weka</url>
  </scm>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>performRelease</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <!-- used for skipping tests -->
      <id>no-tests</id>
      <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-cup-11b</artifactId>
      <version>2015.03.26</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-cup-11b-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2015.03.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>bounce</artifactId>
      <version>0.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java</groupId>
      <artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.f2j</groupId>
      <artifactId>arpack_combined_all</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.netlib-java</groupId>
      <artifactId>netlib-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <weka.main.class>weka.gui.GUIChooser</weka.main.class>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <directory>dist</directory>
    <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>build/testcases</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
        <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.arff</include>
          <include>**/*.cost</include>
          <include>**/*.cup</include>
          <include>**/*.default</include>
          <include>**/*.excludes</include>
          <include>**/*.flex</include>
          <include>**/*.gif</include>
          <include>**/*.icns</include>
          <include>**/*.ico</include>
          <include>**/*.jflex</include>
          <include>**/*.jpeg</include>
          <include>**/*.jpg</include>
          <include>**/*.kfml</include>
          <include>**/*.matrix</include>
          <include>**/*.png</include>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.props</include>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
          <include>**/DatabaseUtils.props.*</include>
          <include>weka/gui/beans/README</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <targetPath>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</targetPath>
        <directory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.arff</include>
          <include>**/*.cost</include>
          <include>**/*.cup</include>
          <include>**/*.default</include>
          <include>**/*.excludes</include>
          <include>**/*.flex</include>
          <include>**/*.gif</include>
          <include>**/*.icns</include>
          <include>**/*.ico</include>
          <include>**/*.jflex</include>
          <include>**/*.jpeg</include>
          <include>**/*.jpg</include>
          <include>**/*.kfml</include>
          <include>**/*.matrix</include>
          <include>**/*.png</include>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.props</include>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
          <include>**/DatabaseUtils.props.*</include>
          <include>weka/gui/beans/README</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            </includes>
            <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
              <weka.test.Regression.root>src/test/resources/wekarefs</weka.test.Regression.root>
              <weka.test.maventest>true</weka.test.maventest>
              <user.timezone>Pacific/Auckland</user.timezone>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <tagBase>https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/tags</tagBase>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <!-- tests are performed with the ant build file, hence skipped here. -->
            <preparationGoals>clean verify -P no-tests</preparationGoals>
            <goals>deploy -P no-tests</goals>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>.</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*~</include>
                <include>**/.attach_pid*</include>
                <include>**/hs_err_pid*</include>
              </includes>
              <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>${weka.main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-test-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <maxmemory>1000m</maxmemory>
          <subpackages>weka:org</subpackages>
          <show>public</show>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/doc</outputDirectory>
          <!-- when using Java 8, use this setting to avoid overly strict javadoclet -->
          <!--additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam-->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: In which folder are the images located? Also show your `pom.xml` file please.

Comment: Images in src/main/java/weka/gui. Question updated with more relevant details.

Comment: Why do you generate your jar using eclipse instead of using the official, IDE-independant maven build?